# AS3: Multiple switch/case functions VS one big one

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, switch-statement

I've got 3 different switch functions that have about 4 cases each. Would it really be so bad to jam all the cases into one big switch function instead? I know it would have to go through more cases that way until it found the proper one, but wouldn't the performance hit be negligible? I'm trying to cut down on needless code so I don't have to scroll through it so much. It would save on some function declarations as well.

To clarify, I have several functions where the user can choose something. Each of those functions has a corresponding handler that uses a switch statement to see what the user chose. I'm considering just using 1 handler instead that has all of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean that.

```
if(x < 4)
{
   switch(x)
   {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   }
}
else if(x < 8)
{
   switch(x)
   {
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
   case 7:
   }
}
else
{
   switch(x)
   {
   case 8:
   case 9:
   case 10:
   case 11:
   default:
   }
}
```

it's better you make a big switch for all because of "code readability". That switch stuff doesn't effect on performance if you're just asking for 3 switches and 4 cases each... you don't need to do that for now...

I think that's really relative to your project. A complete relative discussion depends on project. You're the one who's gonna decide about that stuff.

Comment: No, it's not like that. They have different conditions. In my case, it would logically make more sense to have them separate.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i mean, so, then keep them seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Putting them into one switch statement is a better practice, if the condition is the same of course. SWITCH statement does not exist in the bytecode level, so if you use more SWITCH statements then the bytecode will be way longer. [Check this article.](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/793)